# Escaping special meaning of characters while matching patterns formed using variables: PHP:preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I am performing a regular expression matching to find the first occurrence of some specific set of words in a text. Since I don't want to generate false positives when they are sub strings of some other word, I want to use patterns.

For example, I want to find the whole word "**DOM**" but not the substring DOM in "**RANDOMIZER**", say. So, I am using the pattern as "**\bDOM\b**" to consider all those occurrences of DOM with word boundary on either side. But DOM, ansd other such pattern strings are coming from an array $tags. Reading each tag into $tag from $tags, the comparison would actually be:

```
preg_match("/\b$tag\b/", ...)
```

But this would get into trouble if $tag = "**.NET**". Then "\b$tag\b" will start matching strings like **CNET**, **INET**, etc. interpreting **.** as a wildcard character. So, how do we escape the special meaning of the characters inside a variable that is being used to form the pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote).

> **preg_quote()** takes *str* and puts a backslash in front of every character that is part of the regular expression syntax. This is useful if you have a run-time string that you need to match in some text and the string may contain special regex characters.

Example #1:

```
$keywords = '$40 for a g3/400';
$keywords = preg_quote($keywords, '/');
echo $keywords; // returns \$40 for a g3\/400
```

Comment: Thanks, being a beginner with PHP, I had not come across preg_quote